# Homotopy between curves in $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm learning complex analysis but I stumbled across this problem which I cannot solve:

Let $\alpha_1(t)=e^{it}$ , with $t\in[0,2\pi]$ the circle with radius 1 and centered at the origin.

I need to find an homotopy from this circle to the the curve composed by the circle with radius $1/4$ and center in $1/2$, the circle with radius $1/4$ and center $-1/2$, and the line segment between those circles traversed in both directions.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you asked for an *explicit formula* for a homotopy (messy), or is it sufficient to draw a picture of one?

Comment: The book asks for an explicit formula, I don't know how to define it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will let you derive the formula for this homotopy, but consider the picture below. For $-1/2 \le x \le 1/2$, you can do a straight line homotopy in the vertical direction. For $x \le -1/2$ you can a straight line homotopy along lines passing through the point $-1/2$; similar for $x \ge 1/2$. This defines the homotopy in 8 pieces (depending on where $x$ lies relative to the numbers $-1,-1/2,-1/4,1/4,1/2,1$, and on the sign of $y$).

[image]

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot, now it makes sense!

Comment: No problem :) Of course this isn't the only possible homotopy.